get current deployment name using fabric.io using java
I am trying to get current namespace and deployment name while using fabric.io.
For namespace, I am using: k8sClient.getConfiguration().getNamespace()
Any idea what should I be using for getting current deployment name?
I am deploying my code(using a pod) with a certain deployment name, like: "helm install myDeploymentName ." I need to get the name: "myDeploymentName"

What do you mean by "current deployment name"? You can list all deployments in a given namespace. But there is no "default" deployment.

I am deploying my code(using a pod) with a certain deployment name, like: "helm install myDeploymentName ." I need to get the name: "myDeploymentName"

Are you looking for the name of the Deployment that's managing your current Pod, or the name of the Helm chart that deployed that?  Does your Helm chart include the .Release.Name as a label on the generated Pods?  Why do you need this bit of information?


Usually pod name is written to /etc/hostname.
You can rely on Kubernetes Downward API to expose pod information to environment variables or files (see example here).

You can fetch pod by using this name from either of the above approaches and get name of owner ReplicaSet from .metadata.ownerReferences. Then get owner Deployment of found ReplicaSet from ReplicaSet's .metadata.ownerReferences
Here is some code to get Deployment name using approach 1:

    public String getDeploymentName() {
        File hostName = new File("/etc/hostname");
        try {
            // Get Pod name either by reading the file or via environment variable exposed using Downward API
            String podName = new String(Files.readAllBytes(hostName.toPath()));
            Pod pod = client.pods().inNamespace("default").withName(podName).get();
            OwnerReference replicaSetOwnerRef = getControllerOwnerReference(pod);
            if (replicaSetOwnerRef != null) {
                ReplicaSet replicaSet = client.apps().replicaSets().inNamespace("default").withName(replicaSetOwnerRef.getName()).get();
                OwnerReference deploymentOwnerRef = getControllerOwnerReference(replicaSet);
                if (deploymentOwnerRef != null) {
                    Deployment deployment = client.apps().deployments().inNamespace("default").withName(deploymentOwnerRef.getName()).get();
                    return deployment.getMetadata().getName();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            // Handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    private OwnerReference getControllerOwnerReference(HasMetadata resource) {
        return resource.getMetadata().getOwnerReferences().stream()
            .filter(o -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(o.getController()))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
    }


Thanks. This worked. There were few issues with forbidden error which I needed to resolve using serviceaccount, role and rolebinding.

@SwarajShekhar: Cool, glad to hear it worked for you!
